# Why was my answer edited?

Tags: discussion

My answer to [this question](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/117795/does-it-make-any-sense-to-bribe-the-whole-fbi-in-ozark-season-4/118005#118005) was edited by a Moderator, and the result was a less complete explanation, which resulted in a downvote (or perhaps the Mod downvoted it?).  The edited paragraph was factual and based on Congressional findings.  Politics or not, it was accurate and shouldn't have been edited, the result of which caused harm to the answer.  I want to ask this here before I ask in Meta SE, because if Mods are editing answers because they don't agree with them, those Mods need to be removed.

Answer (score 9):

The moderators have not edited your answer willy-nilly out of personal political disagreement, but in response to multiple flags of it *supposedly* containing wrong information furthering a political agenda. The moderator reviewing those flags, in lack of acquaintance with the event adressed in the answer, did a cursory investigation of it and according to common sources (specifically Wikipedia), found the statements in the deleted paragraph to be of questionable truth.

Given that the information in that paragraph seemed to be controversial at best (and largely fictional at worst) rather than the real factual event it was claimed to be *and* was not directly an example of the issue asked about in the question either, it was deemed better for the sanity of the site and its community to just leave this policitcal issue out of the answer (if in turn, the entire answer foots on this debatable claim, that's rather unfortunate).

This is not really about agreement. There is nothing to agree or disagree about it. From what I could find about the matter, it simply did not happen as factually as stated in the answer and didn't add anything to the discussion other than unrelated political controversy. If you want to take this to MSE and call for the moderators' heads over removing a paragraph with the factual consistency of a Trump Tweet from your answer after multiple users flagged it for questionable merits, knock yourself out. But once moderators stop looking into flags and acting on them accordingly, there wouldn't be a need to remove them anymore, since they're gone.

(I can also confirm that the downvote (or at least *a* downvote) existed *before* your answer was thus edited, so it certainly can't have been caused by the supposedly less complete answer. If anything, it received an upvote after the edit.)

Comment: https://www.cnn.com/2022/05/24/politics/fbi-trump-russia-sussmann-trial/index.html
LITERALLY the first hit in a google for "fbi probe into trump".  But, I'm sure your extensive research wasn't biased at all.  "Factual consistency of a Trump tweet". Yep, no bias at all. Thanks for confirming. ;-)

Comment: Look, Johnny. If you cry "wolf" often enough, people stop believing in wolves. There were flags with links to Wikipedia articles. Now you come with some news article that says...something. Maybe linking to this in your answer would have helped to be more precise than some broad sweeping statement. But at the end of the day this whole thing is clear as mud to me and I'd rather people leave their opinions about US politics *out* of their posts because all it ever does is rile them up against eachother and battling eachother with news articles.

Comment: I will consult with SE staff on the issue, but I do stand to the decision to remove the paragraph from your answer for exactly the reasons described here. And I'd also do it again in similar cases where broad sweeping statements are made and counter-flags arrive to a topic that is only marginally relevant to the answer and that can't be discussed without two diametrically opposed parties ripping eachother's throats out, which is the case for basically every single political issue in that country.

Comment: @JohnnyBones please remember that most people are not from the US, and have little knowledge of and less interest in, the politics of the US. Why would you think the mods here would be biased one way or another? I know that at least three of the four of them are not from US or even the same continent as the US. It seems quite unlikely that there will be bias about some random politician in some far away country.

Comment: @terdon - The question asked, essentially, if the FBI was corruptable.  I stated a case where it was determined the FBI was caught being corrupt.  My entire answer hinged on the instance which was easily provable.  It wasn't so much about politics, although in the US these days pretty much *everything* is.  Apparently, even answers to questions about corrupt government agencies.

Comment: "the FBI was caught being corrupt" There is zero evidence for that claim.

Comment: @Giacomo1968 - What do you think the outcome of a corrupt government agency investigating itself will be?  C'mon, man.  LMAO.  We all know Struck and Paige were anti-Trump agents.  There's no question about that.  And they directed the probe to phonetap a Presidential candidate based on information they never checked.  These are indisputable facts.  Whether the FBI wants to admit, verify or give weight to it or not, these are facts.